# code sleeping in while loop expect the output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
        fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of above on my machine is

```
hello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-err
```

I had to kill the program to stop it.
Is it the correct and expected behavior.
Or it is wrong.This was an interview question hence I am posting here.

Comment: Are you asking a question. Is your question mark key broken.

Comment: I see a question in there, it lacks a question mark. But you can probably identify it too if you wanted.

Comment: 10K users can see an identical question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283556/buffering-for-stdout-stderr-streams), which was deleted for some reason. A shame, because it had good answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the expected output:

- The program loops forever because of the `while (1)` loop.
- `stdout` is line-buffered (by default), so it only flushes to the console when a new-line character (`'\n'`) is printed.  As you aren't printing any new-line characters, you never see any of the `hello-out` text.
- However `stderr` is not line-buffered (by default), so it updates the console on every new `fprintf()` call.

Comment: I replaced `sleep(1)` with `usleep(9000)`. And did `./a.out 2> /dev/null` . I saw that hello-out was printed. Is that an operating system related issue that when buffer gets full it `flushes` it? [On Ideone](http://www.ideone.com/cUExK). Edit : Seth's answer mentions it.

Answer (score 5):

`stdout` is buffered on most machines.  You won't see any output from any `fprintf` calls to `stdout` unless you print a newline or call `fflush()`.

So yes, it's expected behaviour, most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

While everyone is right that you have an infinite loop, stderr is not buffered so you get it immediately, stdout is line buffered so it is deferred until you get a newline, they do not mention that stdout does not have infinite storage.  I think the buffers are 1k or so by default (see setbuf).  If you wait long enough you will get a very long burst of hello-out sequences.  It is entirely possible that the last hello-out might be truncated part of the way through the string "hello-out".

```
[...]hello-outhello-outhellhello-errhello-err
                       ^^^^
```